# Add image, replace, crop, delete section

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

I have an image gallery containing `Add image`, `Add video`, and `description` fields. After adding the image, I have a button on the top right with these functions: `Replace the image`, `Adjust/crop`, `Delete`, `Add Description`, and `Delete Description` that is shown in the attached image. `Add Image` function is working well, but I don't have an idea about the rest of the sections that replace image, crop, and etc.
Can someone help me to find out the solution or does someone have a reference like this?

[image]

```html
<div class="blog-box">
            <div class="c-share">
                      <input class="c-share__input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox5">
                        <label class="c-share__toggler" for="checkbox5">
                        <span class="c-share__icon"></span>
                          </label>
                         <ul class="c-share_options">
                         <li><img src="images/icon/replace-icon.png" class="mr-5">Replace Image</li>
                         <li><img src="images/icon/crop-icon.png" class="mr-5">Adjust / Crop</li>
                         <li><img src="images/icon/delete-icon.png" class="mr-5">Delete</li>
                         <li><img src="images/icon/add-description-icon.png" class="mr-5">Add Description</li>
                         <li><img src="images/icon/add-description-icon.png" class="mr-5">Delete Description</li>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
              <div class="tile"> 
               <div class="flip-card-3D-wrapper">
               
                <div id="flip-card">
                 <div class="flip-card-front">
                 <div class="img-wrap">
                  <div class="cropme" id="landscape" style="width: 350px; height: 400px;"></div>
                  </div>
                   <button id="flip-card-btn-turn-to-back">Add Video</button>
                    <textarea name="form_message" class="form-control required border-r-none ht-gallery-new" rows="5" placeholder="Add Description" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                  </div>
                 <div class="flip-card-back"><div class="inner">
                   <div class="description">
                      <p><strong>Note:</strong> <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">Click</a> here to see how to find embedded video url</p>
                        <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Paste Embedded Video Url Here" name="gmap" class="form-control allow_only_alphabet space video-url-new">
                        <textarea name="form_message" class="form-control required border-r-none add-des-new" rows="5" placeholder="Add Description" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                <img src="images/return-btn.png" id="flip-card-btn-turn-to-front" class="return-btn-bg"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="clear">
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what js framework you are using, or if any of your backend stuff. but this jquery solution might help you:

[Not able to replace the image in the place of old image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876413/not-able-to-replace-the-image-in-the-place-of-old-image-using-javascript)

there is a link there to a snippet where he made a image replacer that allows you to crop the image before replacing. its not working perfectly, but maybe you can work with it.

I would change it to take image URLs tho.

because then for delete, it could be done with a button that sets the src of the img-tag to blank.

```
<div id='imagediv'>
    
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Delete</button>
```

```
var html = "<img src='"+ link +"' >"
var link = "urltoimage.com/picture.jpg"

function myFunction() {
  link = "path to blank image"
  document.getElementById("imageDiv").innerHTML = html;
}
```

i havent tested this, and its not the most amazing way of doing things, but i hope its of some help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and giving your prompt time...I will check with this may be this will help to me